# How do I redirect stdout from a program continuously into a spawned process using expect?

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

Need to open telnet, send a few commands and then send stdout from pocketsphinx.

Currently expect will wait until the program is finished and then output everything to the telnet process. 
I need pocketsphix to continuously feed the spawned telnet process.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -d
set send_human {.1 .3 1 .05 2}
spawn telnet 192.168.1.104 23
expect “*”
send "\x01"; send "2\r"
expect “:”
send -h "hello world\r"
send -h "goodbye world\r"
send -h "Test Test Test\r"
send -- [exec pocketsphinx_continuous -infile speech.wav 2> /dev/null ]\n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use expect command `interact` for connecting together two spawned processes.

> By default, `interact` expects the user to be writing stdin and reading stdout of the Expect process
>   itself. The -u flag (for "user") makes interact look for the user as the process named by its argument
>   (which must be a spawned id).
>
> This allows two unrelated processes to be joined together without using an explicit loop. To aid in
>   debugging, Expect diagnostics always go to stderr (or stdout for certain logging and debugging information).
>   For the same reason, the interpreter command will read interactively from stdin.

For example

```
set send_human {.1 .3 1 .05 2}
spawn telnet 192.168.1.104 23
expect “*”
send "\x01"; send "2\r"
expect “:”
send -h "hello world\r"
send -h "goodbye world\r"
send -h "Test Test Test\r"

set sid_telnet $spawn_id
spawn pocketsphinx_continuous -infile speech.wav 2> /dev/null 

interact -u $sid_telnet
```

Comment: Does interact work for the case where the interactive program is a curses program?

Comment: Sure, it's work with any program which uses terminal